# How to create Api of REST full web Services using Laravel 5.3

Tags: android, laravel, rest, api

I have created CRUD application using laravel 5.3 in XAMPP following [this tutorial](http://georgehk.blogspot.com/2015/04/crud-operations-in-laravel-5-with-mysql.html) now I have to create RESTful API of this CRUD application so that I was able to perform CRUD operation from android app.
anyone who helps Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between API calls and a normal HTML app are basically on the response, usually your controllers respond with views(), so they can be rendered:

```
/// Get the data
$books=Book::all();

/// HTML response
return view('books.index',compact('books'));
```

An API usually responds with JSON, which in Laravel is as easy as doing

```
/// Get the data
$books=Book::all();

/// JSON response
return response()->json($books);
```

or as simple as

```
return Book::all();
```

or

```
return Book::all()->toJson();
```

Another thing you have to think about in your app architecture are the routes, to differentiate web from api, I usually create my endpoints as

```
/api/books/1
```

Instead of

```
/books/1
```

This is done in your routes

```
Route::get('/api/books/{id}', 'BookController@show');
```

You should read a little about API creation too, because API architecture is is hard, endpoints get messy really fast and easy, this is a nice book on APIs https://leanpub.com/build-apis-you-wont-hate

Comment: thank you for your response @Antonio your answer is very help full  now i am getting the json response typing ( localhost:8000/api/books/1 ) in url of browser. but not getting the response in postman using POST (localhost:8000/api/books/1) .it shows ** 405 method not allowed **405 method not allowed <img src="https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipOWmjvo64NERgq9YSNSvSh3dNu4jYeFAj-LC94G/photo/AF1QipO1uVX0dkFEoa-3eDE4ZpRTmIlRXftRm1BSk7He" width="100" height="100">  
and when i use GET it says **ok  (200) ** but not shows the json

Comment: web.php (route file)
`Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});`


`Auth::routes();`
`Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::resource('books','BookController');`


`Route::get('/api/books/{id}', 'BookController@show');`
`Auth::routes();`

`Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: Bookcontroller 

`public function show($id)
   { 
$books=Book::all();
 return response()->json($books);
}`

Comment: removing auth::routes()  and middle ware  now i getting the Json response  using get method 
but how to use the other methods what are there routs  kindly help

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and you should see what are all your routes